# Python TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

Tags: python, typeerror, nonetype

I am getting an error from this code:

```
def make_int(var):
    if len(var) != 0:
        var = int(var)
    return var
```

error:

`TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()`

How do i fix this?

Comment: Check `var is not None` first.

Comment: show us the parameter you're passing to that function...

Comment: You might want to change your test to just `if var:`, which will catch both empty strings and None.

Comment: It sounds as if you are expecting a string, not `None`, as the unconvertible argument. It would be simpler to just *try* `int(var)`, and returning `var` if you catch any exception.

Comment: @FrankYellin But it would pass for anything of truthy value, such as non-empty string. So `int('asdf')` would still break

Comment: If `var` is something that cannot be converted to an integer, what do you want this function do?

Comment: The _quickest_ fix is to not call the function with var equal to `None`.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you are trying to avoid a `ValueError` when calling `int(var)`, but failing to anticipate all the things that could cause one. Don't try; in this case, you are passing an argument that doesn't raise a `ValueError` anyway (`int(None)` raises a `TypeError` instead). Just catch the exception and return `var` if it happens.

```
def make_int(var):
    try:
        return int(var)
    except Exception:
        return var
```

Answer (score -1):

use this snippet

```
def make_int2(var):
    if isinstance(var, str) and var.isdigit():
        return int(var)
    return None
```